# Network application

Tags: java, mysql, percona

I'm developing a network application, which will handle a lot of transactions, so I'm using INNODB as storage engine & Transactions, so do I need to use a LockTable also?

As I know they don't work together. Please give me the best solution to do it.

Comment: Can i use Locking Table with transactions in MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)?

Comment: Yes, but i received a java Code that using the locking table with transactions i don't want to wast time on it, so i need to know if it a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are asking about table locking with respect to InnoDB, as it supports [row-level locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transaction-model.html). I would just focus on making sure your transactions are written correctly and let MySQL take care of the rest.